# Como acessar o index corretamente para dados no mesmo arquivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, índices

Tenho um arquivo

arquivo.txt:

```
>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC
GGATTGTCAATATGCTAAAACGCGGAGTAGCCCGTGTGAGCCCCTTTGGGGGCTTGAAGAGGCTGCCAGC
>gb:HM045792|Organism:Chikungunya virus|Strain Name:'Vereeniging'|Segment:null|Host:Human
ACGTAGCCTACCAGTTTCTTACTGCTCTACTCTGCAAAGCAAGAGATTAAGAACCCATCATGGATCCTGT
GTACGTGGACATAGACGCTGACAGCGCCTTTTTGAAGGCCCTGCAACGTGCGTACCCCATGTTTGAGGTG
GAACCTAGGCAGGTCACACCGAATGACCATGCTAATGCTAGAGCGTTCTCGCATCTAGCTATAAAACTAA
TAGAGCAGGAAATTGATCCCGACTCAACCATCCTGGATATCGGTAGTGCGCCAGCAAGGAGGATGATGTC
>gb:KY474305|Organism:Dengue virus 1|Strain Name:00099-S|Segment:null|Subtype:1|Host:Human
CGAATCGGAAGCTTGCTTAACGTAGTTCTAGCAGTTTTTTATTAGAGAGCAGATCTCTGATGAACAACCA
ACGGAAAAAGACGGGTCGACCGTCTTTCAATATGCTGAAACGCGCGAGAAACCGCGTGTCAACTGGTTCA
CAGTTGGCGAAGAGATTCTCAAAAGGATTGCTTTCAGGCCAAGGACCCATGAAATTGGTGATGGCTTTCA
TAGCATTTCTAAGATTTCTAGCCATACCCCCAACAGCAGGAATTTTGGCTAGATGGAGCTCATTCAAGAA
GAATGGAGCGATCAAAGTGTTACG
```

Estou armazenando essas informações em uma lista e posteriormente em uma tabela no banco de dados porém o índice ou index difere em Host.

code:

```
for item in SeqIO.parse('arquivo.txt', 'fasta'):
    dado = item.description.replace('|', '\n').splitlines()
    print(dado)
    resumo = []

    for i in dado:
        d = i.replace(':', '\n').splitlines()
        resumo.append(d[1])

    id_name = resumo[0]
    organism = resumo[1]
    strain_name = resumo[2]
    segment = resumo[3]
    host = resumo[4]
    seq = item.seq


saída:
 id_name    host     organism         seq           strain_name   segment
 KX262887   Asian   Zika virus      GTTGTTGATCG     103451        null 
 KY474305    1      Dengue virus 1  CGAATCTTACG     00099-S       null
 ...
```

saída esperada:

```
 id_name    host     organism         seq           strain_name   segment
 KX262887   Human   Zika virus      GTTGTTGATCG     103451        null 
 KY474305   Human   Dengue virus 1  CGAATCTTACG     00099-S       null
...
```

Como posso acessar os índices corretamente e armazena-los na tabela?

Comment: Considera usar pandas?

Comment: Sim. Se resolver o problemaI considero usar qualquer biblioteca em Python.... @Miguel

Comment: E os nomes das colunas são fixo? Ou vão ser dinamicos?

Comment: Fixos. Tabela Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um problema pois nem todos os dados tem o mesmo comprimento, portanto acessando esses valores a partir dos índices pode causar resultados inesperados.

Então aqui vai uma outra forma de acessar esses dados de maneira mais simples e sem utilizar nenhuma outra biblioteca adicional.
Os dados são separados com o `split()` e agrupados em um dicionário usando `dict()`:

```py
for item in SeqIO.parse('arquivo.txt', 'fasta'):
    resumo = dict(x.split(":") for x in item.description.split("|"))
    id_name = resumo["gb"]
    organism = resumo["Organism"]
    strain_name = resumo["Strain Name"]
    segment = resumo["Segment"]
    host = resumo["Host"]
    seq = item.seq
```